# Normal login regex

Tags: regex, boost-regex

I want to check login with regex.

1. Login must contain at least 3-16 characters `({3,16})`
2. Login can contains only alphanumeric, `-` and `_` `([a-zA-Z0-9_-])`
3. Login can **NOT** contain `__, --, -_, _-` `((?!--|__|-_|_-))`
4. Login can **NOT** contain `-` or `_` at the end. `((?!-|_))`

How to combine all of expressions into one?

**EDIT:**
5. Login can **NOT** start with `-` or `_`

Comment: `([a-zA-Z0-9]|[\-_][a-zA-Z0-9])+` gets everything except rule 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^(?!_|-)([a-zA-Z0-9]|[\-_](?!_|-|$)){3,16}$`

Matches

-the start of the string

-checks that the first character is not `_` or `-`

-a token that is (one alphanumerical) OR (one hyphen/underscore that is NOT followed by a hyphen/underscore/end of line)

-the above token, 3 to 16 times

-the end of the string

Comment: Thanks, I forgot, login can **NOT** start with with `_` or `-`, how?

Comment: @Shamil Yakupov Like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use positive assertions:

- Login must contain at least 3-16 characters ({3,16})

  ```
  (?=.{3,16}$)
  ```
- Login can contains only alphanumeric, - and _ ([a-zA-Z0-9_-])

  ```
  (?=[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*$)
  ```
- Login can NOT contain **, --, -_, *- ((?!--|***|-|_-))

  ```
  (?!.*(?:__|--|-_|_-))
  ```
- Login can NOT containn nor start with  - or _

  ```
  (?![_-]|.*[_−]$)
  ```

Result:

```
^(?![_-]|.*(?:__|--|-_|_-)|.*[_-]$)[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,16}$
```